# Palantir Foundry Hubble: Boolean column in Hubble Object is displayed as yes/no instead of true/false

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have an Hubble Object that contains a boolean column/property. In "Object Explorer" that property is visualized as "Yes" and "No" instead of "True" and "False". This turns out to be a problem if you want to filter that property with a typescript function and ".isFalse()". It won't get an hit as it cannot find "false" (because it's "no").
I couldn't find a setting to turn of that "conversion" from true/false to yes/no.
Please help :-) Thank you

Comment: Hey @Sensenmann69, could you please share a screenshot or more details about your Typescript function? Also, is your function in a Code Repository? For more context: Hubble renders booleans as "Yes"/"No", but because the underlying dataset still contains `true` and `false` values, you can filter boolean values via `<propertyName> == false` or `<propertyName> == true` in Typescript.